# AngularJS $watchCollection not being called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, watch, angular-controller

I am trying to use `$scope.$watchCollection` from a controller to monitor a service I have. When my controller is originally called, the watch gets called, but every time after it doesn't.

My controller:

```
.controller('LoginModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', '$http', 'loginService', function($scope, $modalInstance, $http, loginService) {

    $scope.$watchCollection('loginService.service', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log("New Data", newVal);
        $scope.service = newVal;
    });

    $scope.closeDialog = $modalInstance.close;
}])
```

My Service:

```
.service('loginService', ['$http', '$filter', function($http, $filter) {
    var service = {
        showGDPR: false,
        showGDPRModal: false,
        invalidCredentials: false
    };
    return ({
        returnVariables: function(){
            return service;
        },
        login: function login(isValid, username, password) { //Called on toggle
        //This function changes the values inside service
        }
    });
 }]);
```

Comment: `$watchCollection` watches the properties of the object. If you're returning functions as properties, how will the watcher work? You could try returning the service directly or as part of an anonymous function(similar to `$watch`).

Comment: @cst1992 I'm not exactly sure what you mean? Since my `login` function changes service.showGDPR to true, is that not a property of the object `service` being changed? To your second point, is my function `returnVariables` similar to what you mean?

Comment: Try removing `returnVariables: ` and just use `function()` and see if there's any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You are using **`$watchCollection`** over a object, use just $watch

```
$scope.$watch('loginService.service', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log("New Data", newVal);
        $scope.service = newVal;
});
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection But isn't `$watchCollection` for objects while `$watch` is for functions?

Comment: Also, that solution has the same issue mine does.